# What can I use instead of cbind() to bind two dataframes when one dataframe does not exist using R?

Tags: r

Assume I have a dataframe made from JSON.
I want to merge list Key from table A and column DUMMY.

```
A<-fromJSON('[{"Key":{"Name":"Victor","ID":61426},"Type":"Unknown","Domain":"Cooking"  }]')


B<-cbind(a$Key, a$DUMMY)
```

> arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

I want to use a kind of cbind, so that if list does not exist, it takes columns that exist.va

```
cbind(A$A,A$DUMMY)
```

Comment: Not true. Please provide a full reproducible example as asked for at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.Using `BOD` which comes with R,  `BOD2 <- BOD; cbind(BOD$Time, BOD2$X)` is such that X does not exist in BOD2 but the answer is the same as `cbind(BOD$Time)` and no error is given.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck sorry, indeed cbind does not give an error for columns using dataframes. I updated my question because I have data from JSON format.

Comment: Where does your dummy come from? Is it a part of the JSON? Then my answer should work. If not, you could try `bind_cols` from the `tidyverse`

Comment: Dummy is just random column names. I run a code where different tables are extracted from the database, so one has DUMMY column, other has not. If DUMMY exist, then no problem to do cbind(), however when DUMMY does not exist, then the error come. I tried bind_cols(), however it does not preserve the names of the tables, the same situation if cbind() is used after with flatten option in fromJSON().

Answer (score 0):

`flatten` from `jsonlite` should do the trick in your case.

You can either directly set it in the JSON-import:

```r
library(jsonlite)

A<-fromJSON('[{"Key":{"Name":"Victor","ID":61426},"Type":"Unknown","Domain":"Cooking"  }]',
            flatten = T)

str(A)
#> 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ Type    : chr "Unknown"
#>  $ Domain  : chr "Cooking"
#>  $ Key.Name: chr "Victor"
#>  $ Key.ID  : int 61426
```

Or do it separately:

```
A<-fromJSON('[{"Key":{"Name":"Victor","ID":61426},"Type":"Unknown","Domain":"Cooking"  }]')

str(A)
#> 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ Key   :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ Name: chr "Victor"
#>   ..$ ID  : int 61426
#>  $ Type  : chr "Unknown"
#>  $ Domain: chr "Cooking"

str(flatten(A))
#> 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ Type    : chr "Unknown"
#>  $ Domain  : chr "Cooking"
#>  $ Key.Name: chr "Victor"
#>  $ Key.ID  : int 61426
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>